# Wrong order of MVC Script Bundles after debug set to false

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

**UPDATE: After some time the bundling works fine, dont know what it was )**

In my BundleConfig.cs I have these bundles defined

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles) 
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/vendor").Include(
        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
        "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
        "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js",
        "~/Scripts/es6-shim.js",
        "~/Scripts/toastr.js",
        "~/Scripts/angular.js",
        "~/Scripts/angular-route.js",
        "~/Scripts/highcharts.src.js",
        "~/Scripts/highcharts-ng.js",
        "~/Scripts/angular-block-ui.js",
        "~/Scripts/angular-translate.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/app").Include(
        "~/Scripts/app/app.js",
        "~/Scripts/app/directives.js",
        "~/Scripts/app/translation.js",
        "~/Scripts/app/data.service.js",
        "~/Scripts/app/main.controller.js",
        "~/Scripts/app/parameters.controller.js",
        "~/Scripts/app/schedules.controller.js",
        "~/Scripts/app/settings.controller.js",
        "~/Scripts/app/subscriptions.controller.js"));
}
```

In my Index.cshtml file I have **this sequence of adding these bundles**

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/vendor")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/app")
```

If in web.config

`<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">`

I have correct bundle sequence

[image]

If I change debug to false

`<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5">`

**the sequence is broken, and the app doesnt work!**

**Why is this happening? How to fix?**

[image]

Comment: Ignore the order of the requests made by the browser, the important thing is the order of the rendered `<script>` elements. Please post your **rendered HTML**.

Comment: Are the *bundles* rendered out of order, or the scripts *inside* each bundle that are out of order?  You have a screenshot, but I cannot see it due to firewall restrictions.

Comment: the bundels, the scripts too, but bundles order is what breaks

Comment: Dai, the last screenshot is how the scripts are added in HTML

Comment: The section `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/app")` can be messed up due to having same name (`app`) as script placeholder directory name `~/Scripts/app`. Try renaming bundle name after `bundles` part.

Comment: Tetsuya Yamamoto.I'll give it a try today and will let you know, thanks

Comment: I'm trying to create scenario , but my solution work correctly . When I set false  compilation debug="false" prop script rendered correctly. firstly vender  secondly app.

Comment: Let me give it another try today

Comment: After some time the bundling works fine, dont know what it was

Comment: What version of `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization` are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It's not typical to use more than one `Scripts.Render` stuck together in a page where you can merge the scripts into one bundle. Such this may be required when you work with partial/conditional scripts in specific views where we use `RenderSection` to meet our purpose.

Your problem comes from the reality which is *bundling order is alphabetical for names with wildcards*. In your case, ***a***pp called before ***v***endor.

**My first solution is** using one `Scripts.Render` if it's possible.

**Second solution would be** to change the place of calling second `Scripts.Render`, say, app scripts like using them in the bottom of page or using `meta` tags between them (not after the vendor to avoid ordering).

**If you want to ensure that scripts are in correct order**, please don't use multiple `Scripts.Render`. Instead, [Configure the ordering for single bundle](https://stevescodingblog.co.uk/changing-the-ordering-for-single-bundles-in-asp-net-4/).

Comment: Amirhossein Mehrvarzi, the problem is that I have tried everything you said ) Alphabetical order is not the reason, I tried to rename bundles, but it didnt change the order. Also the Render commands are in correct order, first I render vendor bundle, then, my scripts bundle. Having two separate bundles is essential, since I need to include vendor libs first. Next I have embedded object JS generation based on server-side cide, and only then, I include my apps bundle.

Comment: I understand what you are saying about preferably using one bundle, that was my target initially, but in our scenario (specifics of the project), vendor and custom scripts must be in two bundles. It is absolutely normal thing to have more than 1 bundle, I just don't get why MVC changes the order. But thanks a lot for the reference about ordering scripts inside the bundle, I will see if I can change something to make this happen, that would be ideal. Will give it a try and will let you know if it worked ))